# MS Access - "This Record Has Been Changed By Another User Since You Started Editing It"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know this has been asked many times, and I have tried many of the suggestions and solutions that worked for others, but I am not able to get this error to go away (please see attachment).  [image: Write Conflict Screenshot]

This is an Access application that is really just a UI to a SQL Server database, and uses all linked tables to the SQL Server database.  The user opens access and they go to a form that opens a "Search", where the user selects a bunch of criteria and clicks "Apply Filter".  A list of records appears that meet their criteria.  They click the record they want, and a form is opened that displays the details about this record.  They then click an "Edit" button that opens another form that allows them to edit certain fields.  When they make changes and hit save is when this error appears.  The odd thing to me, this only occurs if the user selects the first record in the Search list, but it doesn't seem to happen with the others in the list.

What I have tried is the following:

1. Added code on the "BeforeUpdate" and "Update Button Click" event to check "If Me.IsDirty = True Then Me.IsDirty = false" End If.
2. Added a datetime column to the SQL database that gets updated with a trigger ON UPDATE
3. Verified the database has no bit columns
4. Changed the "Record Locks" property on the form to "Edit Records"

None of these items made a difference.

Any help on what might be causing this is appreciated.

Comment: None of those items makes a difference because none of them address the root problem, which is two people editing the same record at the same time.

Comment: OK, well the first thing you need to do is find out what is causing the conflict in the first place.  Taking random actions is not going to fix it; this is one of those times where your solution needs to be *precise.*

Comment: Why does Access think record is being edited from two sources? Are two users editing same record? Or is code running an UPDATE SQL after user has initiated edit of record on form? Are two forms opening to same record and trying to edit?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: this is a common problem when working with Access forms bound to linked ODBC tables, and anything other than the bound form modifies a record.

Comment: Robert:  two people are not editing the record at the same time.  I can guarantee that as it is still in development and only person has the UI hitting a new table in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*2. Added a datetime column to the SQL database that gets updated with a trigger ON UPDATE*

This could actually be the cause of your problem - Access and Sql Server modifying the same row at the same time is causing the write conflict you see.
I'm afraid you have misinterpreted the valid advice you found.

What you want is a `ROWVERSION` aka `TIMESTAMP` column in your Sql Server table. That helps Access figuring out if a row has changed and solve write conflicts. It is fully automatic and needs no trigger.

More details (Albert always provides *lots* of details :p ) here:
[MS Access Write Conflict - SQL Server - Me = Dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086435/ms-access-write-conflict-sql-server-me-dirty)

If this doesn't help: check if you have any other triggers, and post your VBA code for filter / edit / save.

Comment: Upvoted - the fix is NOT to use a datetime - you MUST use TimeStamp - and TimeStamp is ZERO to do with time - one is not to use a trigger or somesuch. TimeStamp is a "blob" and has little to do with time. The poster is to remove the DateTime + trigger and add a TimeStamp. TimeStamps are NEVER modified by the user or even a trigger. Adding timeStamp and making 100% sure that any bit field has a default of 0, (and is not null) will fix the given issue - this post is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have removed my trigger and "Updated_On" column and added the TimeStamp column.  However, I still experience this error message, but only on the first record in my search list.  It does not happen on any other record I have tried.  I would post my VBA code, but there isn't much here, as it is mostly just Access Forms except for the update portion.

Comment: Well, without your code and any way to reproduce the problem, it is impossible for us to help you. @AMC

Comment: This might have been an issue I overlooked, but I reread the link you posted, and noticed that I also didn't have a clearly defined primary key in the database, as I have an ID column that is an identify field, so the record is unique so it didn't dawn on me that I didn't clearly define it in SQL Server.  I then relinked the table in Access and the issue is correct.  Thank you for the help.  Appreciate it very much.