# Unable to change any data for single record in table. I keep getting a write conflict message. All other data in table can be changed

Tags: ms-access

As stated above, I am unable to change any data in a single record of a table. No other users are in the table or database. I do not have other copies of the database open. I keep getting a write conflict error, with only the "copy to clipboard" and "drop changes" options available to select. Is there any other explanation for why I'd be getting a write conflict error for one record in this table? Could there be something in the VBA that is locking this record? I am able to edit other records in the table, but this single record seems to be locked.

EDIT: as requested by @Andre, here is the full CREATE TABLE statement

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[2450Other_t1](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UPN] [int] NULL,
    [CRID] [int] NULL,
    [bmt_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Visit] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [ContributingCOD] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [NewMalignancyEBV] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [DiseaseStatusNorCR] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [SUBSEQ_T] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Ind_Subseq] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Source_Subseq] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CellTherapy] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Date_CT] [datetime] NULL,
    [GraftFail] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [AGVHDDevelop] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [date agvhd] [datetime] NULL,
    [date agvhd prior] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [grade at diag] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [skin] [int] NULL,
    [gut] [int] NULL,
    [ugi] [int] NULL,
    [liver] [int] NULL,
    [other_sites] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [date max agvhd] [datetime] NULL,
    [cghvd develop] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [cgvhd persist] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [max cgvhd] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [date max cgvhd] [datetime] NULL,
    [on steroids] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [other ist] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Liver Therapy] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [liver agents] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [VodDevelop] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [vod date] [datetime] NULL,
    [chimerism] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best-no cr] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [best pcr] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best pcr detect] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best pcr date] [datetime] NULL,
    [best flow] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best flow detect] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best flow date] [datetime] NULL,
    [best cyto] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best fish] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best fish detect] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best fish date] [datetime] NULL,
    [best karyo] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best karyo detect] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best karyo date] [datetime] NULL,
    [best rad] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best rad detect] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best rad date] [datetime] NULL,
    [best clin] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best clin detect] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [best clin date] [datetime] NULL,
    [post-syst] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [post drug1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [post drug2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [post drug3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [post drug4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp prior] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp intv] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp reason intv] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp clin] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp rad] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp cyto] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp flow] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp pcr] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp chim] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [rlp date intervent] [datetime] NULL,
    [rlp drug1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp drug2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp drug3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp drug4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [current not cr] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [rlp drug5] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp drug6] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp drug7] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [rlp drug8] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MaxSkin] [int] NULL,
    [MaxGut] [int] NULL,
    [MaxUgi] [int] NULL,
    [MaxLiver] [int] NULL,
    [MaxOther] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [ScndMalig] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [scndMaligDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [2cndDoc] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [2NDMALIGDONOR] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [2450Other_t1$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Have you run Compact & Repair?

Comment: @June7, just tried, no luck

Comment: Is this a local table? Linked? (from where?)

Comment: @Andre it's linked to a SQL Server

Comment: Then please add the full CREATE TABLE statement to your question. Some datatypes don't work well with Access frontends, e.g. nullable BIT columns.

Comment: Hm, nothing fishy there as far as I can see. I suggest to add a **rowversion** column to your table, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086435/ms-access-write-conflict-sql-server-me-dirty). -- Also it could be worthwhile to look at the data of the offending record in SSMS, maybe a datetime column has a very off value that is outside of Access's date specs. (not sure if this is possible)

Comment: @Andre thanks for taking a look. I've been able to fix a number of values that were outside the date specs. That's what prompted this actually. I'm trying to change a date value that seems to be off. It shows up as the oldest date in the column, but on face value it's certainly not older (i.e., oldest shows up as 1/1/2016, but the next "oldest value" is 1/1/2000. Clearly the 2000 date is older, but something is going on with the 2016 date). I just can't edit it to fix it like I have all the other ones. I'll take a look at rowversion.

Comment: Try editing the record directly in SSMS.